# Cancel axios get request when typing reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm creating an autocomplete function, so basically whenever I type on search box it will cancel the previous http get request. I checked the jQuery ui autocomplete and that's what they did. Is that possible in axios if yes how can I implement it. So far here's my code for http get request:

```
export function autocompleteSearchTest(value){
    return axios.get(`https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php`,{
        params: {
            q: value
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.data.response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        const result = error.response;
        return Promise.reject(result);
    });
}
```

**Here's the screenshot when I type on the search box:**

[image]

as you can see it doesn't cancel the previous http get request.

Comment: i dont think axios' requests can be cancelled at the moment. There was this implementation https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#cancellation but i reckon it is not recommended.

Comment: If not through axios. is there a way to cancel an http get while typing?

Comment: check this it will be helpful: https://gist.github.com/mzabriskie/ec3a25dd45dfa0de92c2#gistcomment-1416322

Comment: @SydneyLoteria there is this another Promise library called bluebird, i guess you can have a look at that too http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html

Comment: I would start by setting a debouncer or throttler on your typing handler, so that it doesn't fire the `autocompleteSearchTest()` function until the user has stopped typing. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce

Answer (score 36):

Since axios v0.15 you can cancel request:

> You can also create a cancel token by passing an executor function to
>   the CancelToken constructor:

```
var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
var cancel;

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
    // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
    cancel = c;
  })
});

// cancel the request
cancel();
```

For more information please have a look [Cancellation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#cancellation). And according to your code:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

export function autocompleteSearchTest(value) {
    if (cancel != undefined) {
        cancel();
    }
    return axios.get(`https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php`, {
        cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
            // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
            cancel = c;
        }),
        params: {
            q: value
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data.response;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            const result = error.response;
            return Promise.reject(result);
        });
}

var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
var cancel;

export class AutoComplete extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            search: ''
        };
        this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSearchChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        this.setState({
            search: value
        });
        autocompleteSearchTest(value)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App-intro Dialog-section">
                <h2>AutoComplete</h2>
                <div className="form-control">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Lookup :</label>
                    <input name="search" type="text" value={this.state.search}
                           onChange={this.handleSearchChange}
                           id="password" ref="password" placeholder="Enter line"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AutoComplete;
```

And here it's
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### use: react, axios and redux-axios-middleware

user actions:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as type from 'constants/user';

const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

export const addUser = (data) => {
  if (cancel !== undefined) cancel();

  return ({
    types: [type.ADD_USER_REQUEST, type.ADD_USER_SUCCESS, type.ADD_USER_FAILURE],
    payload: {
      request: {
        url: '/api/user',
        cancelToken: new CancelToken(c => cancel = c),
        method: 'POST',
        data,
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create such a small helper wrapper and use it anywhere where you need to cancel previous request:

```js
// ../services.js

function createApi(baseURL) {
  const axiosInst = axios.create({
    baseURL,
  });

  axiosInst.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  
  return (type = 'get') => {
    let call = null;
    return (url, data, config) => {
      if (call) {
        call.cancel('Only one request allowed!');
      }
      call = axios.CancelToken.source();
      const extConf = {
        cancelToken: call.token,
        ...config,
      };
      switch (type) {
        case 'request':
          return axiosInst[type](extConf);

        case 'get':
        case 'delete':
        case 'head':
          return axiosInst[type](url, extConf);

        default:
          return axiosInst[type](url, data, extConf);
      }
    };
  };
}

export const baseApi = createApi('http://localhost:5000/api/')
```

And then use it anywhere like this:

```js
import baseApi from '../servises.js';

const fetchItemsService = baseApi('post');

//...
componentDidMount() {
  fetchItemsService('/items').then(() => {});
}
//...
```

Comment: Where the api from api[type](url, extConf) is imported from? I'm getting this error:

Cannot find name 'api'. with this code

Comment: Sorry @VictorCarvalho I used wrong name `api` should be `axiosInst`, I fixed the code example above.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna use something like RxJS for this, then you can delay the input if the users search, before the requests are made.

Comment: RxJS is overkill for just this, although it's a great solution, it's a big conceptual lift just for debouncing or throttling.

Answer (score 0):

use [faxios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faxios)

```
// building..
let req = faxios()
  .baseURL("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
  .url("posts", 1, "comments")

// fetching..
req // => 
  .FETCH // => Promise
  .then(res => {})
  .catch(err => {});

// canceling...
req.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you can cancel token using axios with this

```
export function autocompleteSearchTest(value){
const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source()// 1st
return axios.get(`https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php`,{
    params: {
        q: value
    }
})
.then(response => {
    return response.data.response;
})
.catch(error => {
 if (axios.isCancel(e)) return //3rd
    const result = error.response;
    return Promise.reject(result);
});

 return () =>{ // 2nd
        cancelToken.cancel();
    }
}
```